# How to convert dates of this kind to month-day-year format?

Tags: date, datetime, date-format, mktime

I have to convert the following date format to m-d-Y format. How can I achieve it?
`$date='Thu, 20 Jun 2013 09:09:52 UTC'` and what I am suppose to pass in query is `6-20-2013`

Please let me know a few quick tricks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date('m-d-Y', strtotime('Thu, 20 Jun 2013 09:09:52  UTC'))`